# Copy Style without remove element another by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is Html:(Example)

```
<div id="id1" style="width:100px;background: rgb(196, 14, 14);">1</div>
<div id="id2" style="margin-top:10px">2</div>

to

<div id="id1" style="width:100px;background: rgb(196, 14, 14);">1</div>
<div id="id2" style="width:100px;background: rgb(196, 14, 14);margin-top:10px">2</div>
```

this is js:

```
var x = $('#id1').clone().attr('style');
$('#id2').attr('style', x);
```

I do not want this code `margin-top:10px` to be deleted.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/behrouzbash/nvm7f0kd/4/)

Comment: do not use any style attribute but use them systematically, and you can reign over your code!

Comment: The best way to achieve this is using "Css Classes". But if you _really_ want to do this:

https://jsfiddle.net/d12ypeLu/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code may help you to update the style attribute dynamically.

```
$('#id2').attr('style', $('#id2').attr('style') + ';' +$('#id1').attr('style'));
```

Comment: The semicolon should already be part of the existing style, right?  (and thus, no need to add it)

Answer (score 0):

So, get the existing style from the element, add x to it, and update the element style attribute with the result. Also, there's no reason to use clone(). Just get the style attribute.

```
var x = $('#id1').attr('style');
var existingStyle = $('#id2').attr('style');
$('#id2').attr('style', existingStyle + ' ' + x);
```

However, a better way to do this would be using classes and CSS.  You can then just use `addClass()` to add the new class to the element.